# How to make one loop out of five in bash?

Tags: bash, macos, scripting

I have a small script for Mac where I'm adding printers. It works fine but I think I could make it simpler or at least it would be interesting to know a different solution.

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do
        if [[ $line == *"Printer_E1"* ]]
        then
                if [[ "$FIND_PRINTERS" =~ "$PRINTER_E1_IP" ]];
                then
                        echo "found printer e1"
                else
                        echo "adding printer e1"
                        "$LPADMIN" -p "$PRINTER_E1_IP" -v "lpd://$PRINTER_E1_IP" -L "$PRINTER_E1_LOCATION" -P "$PRINTER_E1_PPD" -E -o printer-is-shared=false -D "$PRINTER_E1_NAME"
                        echo "adding printer e1 done"
                fi
        fi
done <<< "$AD_GROUPS"
```

The content of $AD_GROUPS is:

```
Printer_E0
Printer_E1
Printer_E2
Printer_E3
Printer_E4
Printer_Strasse
Printer_Wien
```

I have such a loop for 5 printers, so 5 times that just with different variables.
How could I do that with one loop? (or how can I make that different or simpler)?

Comment: `such a loop for 5 printers, so 5 times that just with different variables` how different? Different in what way? Which variables?

Comment: Like in that example I posted, but instead of the variables with "Printer_E1", it's "Printer_E3" in another, or "Printer_somewhere" in another. The only thing that changes are the name of the variables.

Comment: Update your question with the content of AD_GROUPS.

Comment: Im very confused by your code and what you want to achieve. Example: where do you get the variables `FIND_PRINTER` and `FIND_PRINTER_E1_IP` from. This seems to be undefined in the script. Could you be more specific?

Comment: the printer variables are in another file and get loaded via source. I want to achieve that depending which active directory groups a user has and then he adds the printer (if he hasn't it already). So for example if a user has AD-Group "Printer_E1", he will get the printer named "Printer_E1" added.

Comment: Sounds like arrays would help a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r printer; do
    [[ "$FIND_PRINTERS" =~ "${printer}_IP" ]] && \
        echo "Found ${printer}" && continue
    echo "Adding ${printer}..."
    "$LPADMIN" -p "${printer}_IP" \
               -v "lpd://${printer}_IP" \
               -L "${printer}_LOCATION" \
               -P "${printer}_PPD" -E -o printer-is-shared=false \
               -D "${printer}_NAME" \
               && echo "Done"
done <<< "$AD_GROUPS"
```

I assume your variable `FIND_PRINTERS` has some printers you want to skip, that you have already set the parameters (IP, LOCATION etc) related to each printer.

We use the variable inside double quotes into there, so it expands to what you want for the various commands. Also I have simplified the `if condition then command` to `condition && command` and also `continue` moves to next iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but for some weird reason this doesn't seem to work for me. Echoing variables like `"${printer}_IP"` just prints the text but not the variable. At least it's that way for me.

Comment: I test: `printer="test"; echo "${printer}_IP"` and see output `test_IP`. So, it works. I cannot test for your case as I know nothing about the way you set all these variables, where and how you set `Printer_E1_IP` etc. I believe you can debug it  with a few printing statements inside your code.